# How to Create JSON Array for Key Value Pair in java and use it in JQuery Autocomplete to to Separate KEY VALUE

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, gson

I have been trying very hard and have searched everywhere for this solution but no.

I have a JSP Page which has a Jquery autocomplete feature.

```
<body>
    <%
        String ValueRec = request.getParameter("Category");
        String autosuggest = request.getParameter("autosuggest");
        out.println(ValueRec);
        out.println(autosuggest);
    %>
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" id="autosuggest" name="autosuggest" value="N"/>
        <input type="text" name="Category" id="Category" value="" id="CategoryID">
        <script>
            $("#Category").autocomplete({
                delay: 100,
                autoFocus: true,
                selectFirst: true,
                source: 'ProviderSuggest.jsp',
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#autosuggest').val('Y');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

The code for ProviderSuggest.jsp is as follows:

```
    <%@page import="java.util.Hashtable"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="Functions.DBConnections"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
    String query = request.getParameter("term");
    List<String> CategoryList = new DBConnections().GetCategoryList(query);
    Iterator CatIterator = CategoryList.iterator();
    String JCategory = "";
    Map CategoryMap = new HashMap<>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    while (CatIterator.hasNext()) {
        String Category = (String) CatIterator.next();
        String CategoryID = (String) CatIterator.next();
        CategoryMap.put(CategoryID, Category);
        //JCategory = gson.toJson(CategoryMap);
    }
    //System.out.println(CategoryMap);
    JCategory = gson.toJson(CategoryMap);
    System.out.println(JCategory);
    //out.print(JCountry);
    out.print(JCategory);
%>
```

When I type the keywords in the autocomplete field I am getting the categories as required. The ProviderSuggest.jsp is returning the data in the json format, as mentioned below:

```
{"110":"MRI SCAN","101":"CT SCAN","102":"SONOGRAPHY","103":"X-RAY","104":"PATHOLOGY"}
```

I am using Google.gson.Gson.

My requirement is that when the user types e.g. MRI, he should get to see the categories like MRI SCAN, CT SCAN and so on. I am seeing this but the value of the input field should be "110" OR "101" and so on., so that when I further process the data I only send the category ID and not the category.

I would be glad if anyone can help me out with the complete code of how to achieve this. I believe I am making some mistake at the JSon array creation part and the Jquery section where we read the json data.

Thanks.

Comment: You seriously need a Java POJO called Category which contains categoryId and categoryName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render your autocomplete data in this way. Add the categoryid as a data attribute and then on select you will have the a having data- tag and you can retrieve the .data('id') = Category ID. Hope it helps.

```
$("#Category").autocomplete({
  delay: 100,
  autoFocus: true,
  selectFirst: true,
  source: 'ProviderSuggest.jsp',
  select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#autosuggest').val('Y');
  }
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
   return $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a data-id='"+item.CategoryID+"'>" + item.Category + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

And your Java should be like : The intention is to have an Array which has key as id another key as value (2 keys)

`[{CategoryID :"110",Category:"MRI SCAN"},{CategoryID :"101",Category:"CT SCAN"]}`

```
<%@page import="java.util.Hashtable"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="Functions.DBConnections"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
    String query = request.getParameter("term");
    List<String> CategoryList = new DBConnections().GetCategoryList(query);
    Iterator CatIterator = CategoryList.iterator();
    String JCategory = "";
    Map CategoryMap;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List autoComplete = new ArrayList();
    while (CatIterator.hasNext()) {
        String Category = (String) CatIterator.next();
        String CategoryID = (String) CatIterator.next();
        CategoryMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        CategoryMap.put("Category", Category);
        CategoryMap.put("CategoryID", CategoryID);
        //JCategory = gson.toJson(CategoryMap);
        autoComplete.add(CategoryMap);
    }

    JCategory = gson.toJson(autoComplete);
    System.out.println(JCategory);
    //out.print(JCountry);
    out.print(JCategory);
%>
```

Comment: Hi JoyBlanks Thanks for your prompt reply. But I could you help me with the entire code with all the changes that you told me to make in java. as the code mentioned by you is giving me errors.

Comment: If I just copy paste your given code in JSP page it gives me illegal start of expression and the Line CategoryMap = new HashMap<>(); is giving error.

Comment: use this `CategoryMap = new HashMap<String,String>()`

Comment: Thanks Joy. The Java code is generating the Json array as desired but the jquery autocomplete is not displaying anything in the drop down. The request String is getting submitted and the response Json data is also coming but not being displayed under the dropdown.